# Missing items when I loop over a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, oop, zip

I tried to create a student class object, and collect some data and show it:

```
class Student: 

    subjects = []
    grades = []  
    d = {}
    def __init__(self, name, id):
            self.name = name
            self.id = id 


    def addGrade(self, subject, grade):
        self.subjects.append(subject)
        self.grades.append(grade)


    def showGrades(self):
        self.d = dict(zip(self.subjects, self.grades))
        for subject in self.d:
            return subject + ' : ' + str(self.d[subject])
```

when I try add to values:

```
    stu =Student('Zaki', 23)
    stu.addGrade('Math',90)
    stu.addGrade('Physicis',95)
    stu.addGrade('English',100)

    print(stu.showGrades())
```

the output turns to be
Math : 90

and it ignores the other values!

Comment: Please indent your code the same way as when you run it. (Now edited to fix based on what is likely.)

Comment: btw you should move `subjects = []` inside the `__init__()` as `self.subjects = []`. Sames with `grades`. Also `d = {}` does nothing.

Comment: In my answer I have discussed the same point that @quamrana makes. While you only have one instance, you do not realise the problem. As soon as you create a second instance of `Student`, you will see the problem with using class variables for `subjects` and `grades`.

Comment: Mutable class variables (or at least, actually mutating them) is generally a bad idea. Save them for constants which should be the same for all instances.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `return subject + ' : ' + str(self.d[subject])` in showGrades you exit the function, you can't use return in a loop. You should instead parse and format the output to your liking and then use return outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You expect that  `return subject + ' : ' + str(self.d[subject])` in `showGrades` run three times, but when it reaches the first return, it leaves the loop. So, change your `showGrades` code to:

```
def showGrades(self):
    self.d = dict(zip(self.subjects, self.grades))
    ret = []
    for subject in self.d:
        ret.append(subject + ' : ' + str(self.d[subject]))
    return ret # this will return list containing [subject : grade]
```

Output:

```
['Math : 90', 'Physicis : 95', 'English : 100']
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem that you are having is that you are putting an (unconditional) `return` inside the `for` loop (so it returns on the first iteration of the loop), rather than for example, building a list and returning that list after the loop.

However, separate from this, your code is also modifying the class variables, and you will get a surprise if you create another instance `stu2 = Student(...)` and find that this second student already has subjects and grades.

What you need to do to fix this second problem is to make `subjects` and `grades` into instance variables instead - and initialise them in `__init__`.  You could do similarly with your class variable `d`, but it looks like it is probably only for use inside `showGrades` and would probably be best just replaced with a local variable in that method (function).

Putting these together, you could have something like this:

```
class Student: 

    def __init__(self, name, id):
            self.name = name
            self.id = id 
            self.subjects = []
            self.grades = []  


    def addGrade(self, subject, grade):
        self.subjects.append(subject)
        self.grades.append(grade)


    def showGrades(self):
        d = dict(zip(self.subjects, self.grades))
        grades = []
        for subject in d:
            grades.append(subject + ' : ' + str(d[subject]))
        return grades

stu =Student('Zaki', 23)
stu.addGrade('Math',90)
stu.addGrade('Physics',95)
stu.addGrade('English',100)
print(stu.showGrades())  # ['Math : 90', 'Physics : 95', 'English : 100']

stu2 = Student("Juan", 24)
print(stu2.showGrades())  # []
```